# Many To Many collection always null (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with an entity that has a many to many relationship.
If I try to access the collection referring to many to many (via getter) I always have a null pointer exception. I also added `fethType.EAGER` and initialized the collection, but I get the same error.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
@Entity
public class Film implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

   //other

    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "film")
    private Set<Cinema> cinema = new HashSet<>();

//getter and setter


    @Entity
public class Cinema implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "cinema_film", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cinema_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "film_id")})
    private Set<Film> film = new HashSet<>();
```

I have the exception when I try

```
cdb.getFilm().add(fdb);
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Hülya i've edited the post

Comment: Good, but the exception should be able to regenerated with the code you shared. So that one can have the idea of what's wrong. @frodo

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` and `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` in your Cinema class like this.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
```

and `fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in your Film class.